# Google Spreadsheet impossible to read attribute from 0

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

Hello I have several 2018 projects Google Docs and I want to put all theirs URL in a Google Spreadsheet in column A like here so the document Spreadsheet is empty [image]

This is the function I wrote and the error is that he cannot read the attribute from 0 [image] how do i solve this?Thank you very much.

```js
function copy_Docs_2018_vers_Tableau() {
  
  /** on regarde le folder de départ ici FOLDER_ID où on a les documents Google Docs avec les fiches projet 2018 **/
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID); 
  Logger.log('Folder name  ' + folder.getName());
  
  /** on va utiliser les URLs  **/
  var docURLs = [];
  
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID).getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  var file;
  
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    docURLs.push(file.getUrl());
    Logger.log('File URL  ' + file.getUrl());
  }
  Logger.log(docURLs); // message pour voir si on a qq URLs pour la vérification
  
  /** Le Spreadsheet avec la feuille de calcul + les nombres de lignes & colonnes **/
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var sheet = tss.getSheets()[0];
  var numRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  
  // ? à reflechir si on a déja du contenu dans le document ce qu'on aura pour les autres colonnes si on va garder l'ordre des données ou on va le melanger après
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,numRows,lastColumn);
  
 

  
  
  for (var i = 1; i < docURLs.length; i++ ) {
    
    /**  prémierement on va insérer le URL du Google Doc **/
    
    data[i][0].setValue(docURLs[i]); 
    sheet.autoResizeColumn(COLUMN_URL);                          //comme le URL est long on va ajuster la colonne
```

I did with the logs as suggested in the comment thank you in logs i is 1 and the same error 
[image]

Comment: I would try logging `data`, and also `i` inside the loop to see where/why it's breaking.

Comment: In fact I edited the post and also tried var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,numRows,lastColumn).clearContent();
  Logger.log("data ", data);  before the loop so I don't have nothing which is normal because I want to put docURLs in the data[i][0] variable like this without using getRange anymore (data[i][0]  = docURLs[i] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the line `docURLs.push(file.getUrl());` to `docURLs.push([file.getUrl()]);`
2. Change `var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,numRows,lastColumn);` to `var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,docURLs.length,docURLs[0].length);`
3. Delete the for-loop
4. Use the `setValues()` batch method for faster execution: `data.setValues(docURLs);`

In your original code, `data` is a *range*, which you cannot iterate through like you do an array. If you do not want to do the batch operation and instead prefer to print each URL one-by-one, I recommend that you use the `appendRow()` function. So instead of steps 3 and 4 above, you would replace `data[i][0].setValue(docURLs[i])` with `sheet.appendRow(docURLs[i])`